# Different versions of react and React native cause circular dependencies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am having a question regarding version constraints.

First I was trying to install `npm i react-native-message-bar --save`

But then I got an `Unmet Peer dependency`: `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.1.0`

So I did: `npm install react@16.1.0`
But then I got:

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.1.0
npm WARN react-native@0.50.3 requires a peer of react@16.0.0 but none was installed.
```

So I have the feeling that I am running into circular dependencies.

Does this mean that I am not able to use the `react-native-message-bar` . with the current version of react?

I Would like to have some suggestions on how to resolve this.